# truffle test will only run one contract

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ethereum, chai, solidity

I have an instability issue.
I'm using openzeppelin-test-helpers, and first had an issue with typescript saying `Could not find a declaration file for module '@openzeppelin/test-helpers'.`. This issue was solved by creating a `.d.ts` file containing `declare module "@openzeppelin/test-helpers";`.

However, adding this created a new problem, which is that now, most of the time, only one file is being run by `rm -rf build && truffle test` (I guess this is similar to `truffle test --reset`).

I got 2 test files. The first one looks like:

```js
require("chai")
    .use(require("chai-as-promised"))
    .should();

const EventHandler = artifacts.require("EventHandler");
const { expectRevert } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");

contract("EventHandler", function([_, superAdmin0, admin0, device0]) {
    beforeEach(async function() {
        this.eventHandler = await EventHandler.new(superAdmin0);
    });
    describe("Initial tests", function() {
        it("should print hello", async function() {
            await this.eventHandler
                .printHello()
                .should.eventually.equal("Hello");
        });
    });
});
```

The second one looks like:

```js
require("chai")
    .use(require("chai-as-promised"))
    .should();

const { expectRevert } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");

const EventHandler = artifacts.require("EventHandler");

contract("Roles", function([_, superAdmin0, superAdmin1, admin0, device0]) {
    beforeEach(async function() {
        this.EventHandler = await EventHandler.new(superAdmin0);
    });
    it("...should work", async function() {});
});
```

When I comment the content of one file, or just what's inside `contract(..., {})`, the other file works just fine and the tests pass successfully.
However, whenever I leave those 2 files uncommented, I get a massive error:

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
```

Of course, resetting ganache-cli didn't solve anything...

Does anyone know where it could come from?

Comment: If more details are required, it started to work again for some reason, with just additional tests added... I wouldn't be able to explain why.